# Swift and Apple Pay integration: How to implement a callback request for payment confirmation?

Tags: swift, callback, request, payment, applepay

I am trying to implement apple pay and integrate it with the payment system. I send a request as described in the documentation, where I pass all the necessary information, and I receive a response in the following format:

```
{"action":"APPLEPAY","result":"REDIRECT","status":"3DS","order_id":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","trans_id":"xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx","trans_date":"2023-05-23 12:13:59","redirect_url":"https:\/\/xxx.xxx.xx\/api\/v2\/brw\/challenge\/init?txid=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","redirect_params":null,"redirect_method":"GET"}
```

as i understand i need to open url - "redirect_url" I do this with:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in
                            print("Open url : \(success)")
                           })
```

and then a push notification comes from banking confirming the transaction. which I confirm. and payment is charged.
but in the documentation it is described that after passing the "3ds check", I should "receive a callback of successful payment".
which looks like this:

```
{"action":"SALE","result":"SUCCESS","status":"SETTLED","order_id":"xxxxxxx","trans_id":"xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx","trans_date":"2023-05-23 12:13:59","descriptor":nil,"recurring_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","card_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","hash":"********************************"}
```

how do i achieve this? if possible, please provide an example with pseudo code. and am I doing the right thing in opening in this way: "UIApplication.shared.open(urlRed, options: [:], completionHandler: ..."

the support of the payment system said that the "link" for the callback is written on the side of the payment system. but I don't quite understand how it works and how can I get a successful payment response after 3ds